# Angular to send a PDFMake generated PDF document with PHPMailer

Tags: php, angularjs, pdf

Doesn't really work, what I do there. Would like Angular to send a PDFMake generated PDF document with PHPMailer. Somehow I get the PDF document not in the mail to be sent. Either the PDF in the mail is only as an attachment without content or it is issued as PDF attachment but does not open (file defective or damaged)
Has anyone vileicht an idea how I can implement the it works.
The Dynamich generated PDF document is to be transferred to the PHP file so that it is sent as a mail attachment.
Thank you

Here the controllers.js / code:

```
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
// or ---------------------------------
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("Test_PDF.pdf");

    };


// Data to PHPMailer ---------------------------------------

$scope.formData = {
        inputName: 'Test_Name',
        inputEmail: 'test@test.com',
        inputSubject: 'Test_Subject',
        inputMessage: 'Test_Message',
        inputFile: 'Test_PDF.pdf'
    };

    var param = function (data) {

        var returnString = '';

        for (var d in data) {

            if (data.hasOwnProperty(d))

                returnString += d + '=' + data[d] + '&';
        }

        return returnString.slice(0, returnString.length - 1);
    };


$scope.result = 'hidden'
$scope.resultMessage;
$scope.formData;     
$scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
$scope.submitted = false; 

$scope.submit = function(contactform) {
        $scope.submitted = true;
        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
        if (contactform.$valid) {
            $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : 'test_mail.php',
                data    : param($scope.formData),
                headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } 
            }).success(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if (data.success) { 
                    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
                    $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                    $scope.result='bg-success';
                } else {
                    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                    $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                    $scope.result='bg-danger';
                }
            });
        } else {
            $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
            $scope.resultMessage = 'Failed <img src="error.gif" alt=":(" class="wp-smiley">  Please fill out all the fields.';
            $scope.result='bg-danger';
        }

    }
```

Here the test_mail.php files / code:

```
<?php
require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if (isset($_POST['inputName']) && isset($_POST['inputEmail']) && isset($_POST['inputSubject']) && isset($_POST['inputMessage']) && isset($_POST['inputFile'])) {

    if (empty($_POST['inputName']) || empty($_POST['inputEmail']) || empty($_POST['inputSubject']) || empty($_POST['inputMessage']) || empty($_POST['inputFile'])) {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    $mail = new PHPMailer();


    $mail->From = $_POST['inputEmail'];
    $mail->FromName = $_POST['inputName'];
    $mail->AddAddress('test@test.com'); 
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['inputSubject'];
    $mail->Body = "-" . $_POST['inputName'] . "\r\n\r\n - " . stripslashes($_POST['inputMessage']);



    $pdf_pfad = 'data:application/pdf;base64';
    $pdf_file_name = $_POST['inputFile'];
    $encoding = 'base64';
    $type = 'application/pdf';
    $mail->AddStringAttachment($pdf_pfad, $pdf_file_name, $encoding, $type);



    if (isset($_POST['ref'])) {
        $mail->Body .= "\r\n\r\nRef: " . $_POST['ref'];
    }
    if(!$mail->send()) {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Mailer-Error: ??? ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }
    $data = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Mailer-Success - OK');
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Mailer-Error: Please fill out the form completely.');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

Comment: Is pdf file in the same directory with your test_mail.php file?

Comment: No it is generated from Angular with pdfMake and output as a download and should then be sent as an email attachment.

Comment: no idea about how pdfMaker works. But var mypdf = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("Test_PDF.pdf"); should give you the file itself. Then post it to php and review phpMailer docs for how to include posted file as attachment